# How to add view to UIWindow but below view controller which present over?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, viewcontroller, uiwindow

How to add view to UIWindow but below viewcontroller which present over ?

In iOS 13 +, It already have behavior like that (add view to window, it will not over viewcontroller which open by modal presentation ) but on <13.0 it show over everything.

Answer (score 0):

Add this extension

```
extension UIWindow {
    static var key: UIWindow? {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            return UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }
        } else {
            return UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        }
    }
}
```

And Use it in your Class

```
 if let keyWindow = UIWindow.key {
        // Example: keyWindow.addSubview(datePicker)
    }
```